# Line wrap for horizontal legends in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

Is there a way to make the labels in a legend with horizontal direction wrap?
I made a simple example wtih the cars dataset where i transformed the categtories to generate longer strings in the [Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gUVgCcx2XAWJkhtBszacepZJubcjpbbtLx0R2PMUVAF91CEg8I3QlWAAzN1QzAG0NCFAIdKgxbm4Aa1ZCM0gAeSNGJhVQjKgYo24E-RSqyE89MDSqjMgKdDFWZFgkxo7gYtLywoBVAGUAQTUoADlkAHcAGXR2ZFMcSAAVZGQldGpkMABZVl0lPDAFxiU5dDBd4zwxfsgQoaqRkrL7woAUWM3EIyHmkCWaw2W0KCyeRzAiORCNRSLRKLAACEdBglABCT6VDqpUb-FQ7ABS6EIUQhUPWm22UCmOS2yDwbjAIjAqzcmjA3BiYAAIv0Iqx4HgeEowFEBUUqCZ+YLhYCKIxTEFvhAALo6sBfElQNkAT0Kf3GxKaMUYW00AxwiUhK0ZsP1HW1GS9YF1lUgGCMOTM7TCeFNYMK7F8aka4WyYmlBRwEuQGiNUGWjE0LDM0gADPn-ehLtxYIwAF7g-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-pdUdHFYXd-FrW004JTsqB0dKe3xtQ1CPjsyBUNcdBSiYADSyDmktaCEOGiXKOCgXWidA0Xg98XiUVB6PjDqBw2Z66Iz9vUfdwrB5Wjl5LfA7wxmTFPIOTTbXcx-ppbah7Xl0dqTvokCwBEuQCaB+A8VDRJxj5anNHU6D3AA6tmuY4PmPratqQA):
[image]

Suppose I have more categories but also want to put the legend at the top/bottom to provide more horizontal space for the chart area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `columns` property of `legend`:

```
  {
    "legend": {
    "orient": "top",
    "direction": "horizontal",
    "columns": 2
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a custom legend in a separate `div`.

The categories and their mapped colors in the Vega visualization can be accessed via the [View API](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_scale):

```
const colors = vegaView.scale('color').range();
const categories = vegaView.scale('color').domain()
```